# Ordering dataframes within a nested list based on a specific value (=> unique(table[[i]]$COLUMN)[1])?

Tags: r, sorting, nested-lists

Okay.. *deep breath in*

I have a nested list called tables, which is a list of data frames.

These data frames have a common base and their own columns of specific criteria.
I have an undefined number of such data frame that I must compile weekly.

So for example :

> tables[[1]]

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  DATE                SUPERVISOR SECTOR    ACTIVITY   `FERTILIZER#Criterion 1` `FERTILIZER#Criterion 2`
  <dttm>              <chr>      <chr>     <chr>                         <dbl>                    <dbl>
1 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 1  FERTILIZER                        1                        0
2 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 3  FERTILIZER                        1                        0
3 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 6  FERTILIZER                        1                        1
4 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 8  FERTILIZER                        0                        0
5 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 9  FERTILIZER                        0                        0
6 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 13 FERTILIZER                        0                        1
7 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 14 FERTILIZER                        0                        0
8 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 15 FERTILIZER                        0                        0
```

> tables[[2]]

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  DATE                SUPERVISOR SECTOR    ACTIVITY `PLANTING#Criterion 1` `PLANTING#Criterion 2`
  <dttm>              <chr>      <chr>     <chr>                     <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 2022-11-10 00:00:00 AC         SECTOR 6  PLANTING                      1                      0
2 2022-11-11 00:00:00 AC         SECTOR 3  PLANTING                      1                      0
3 2022-11-12 00:00:00 AC         SECTOR 6  PLANTING                      1                      1
4 2022-11-13 00:00:00 AC         SECTOR 8  PLANTING                      0                      0
5 2022-11-14 00:00:00 AC         SECTOR 10 PLANTING                      0                      0
6 2022-11-15 00:00:00 AC         SECTOR 1  PLANTING                      0                      1
7 2022-11-16 00:00:00 AC         SECTOR 1  PLANTING                      0                      0
8 2022-11-17 00:00:00 AC         SECTOR 1  PLANTING                      0                      0
```

So when I bind them together, it produces this :

```
> library(dplyr)
> MEGATABLE <- bind_rows(tables)
> head(MEGATABLE)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  DATE                SUPERVISOR SECTOR    ACTIVITY   `FERTILIZER#Criterion 1` `FERTILIZER#Criterion 2` `Planting#Criterio…` `Planting#Crit…`
  <dttm>              <chr>      <chr>     <chr>                         <dbl>                    <dbl>                <dbl>            <dbl>
1 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 1  FERTILIZER                        1                        0                   NA               NA
2 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 3  FERTILIZER                        1                        0                   NA               NA
3 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 6  FERTILIZER                        1                        1                   NA               NA
4 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 8  FERTILIZER                        0                        0                   NA               NA
5 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 9  FERTILIZER                        0                        0                   NA               NA
6 2022-10-05 00:00:00 BG         SECTOR 13 FERTILIZER                        0                        1                   NA               NA
```

I import the tables via list.files("TABLE_FILE"), they have random names, so their order can be pretty random. Hence, their order in the "tables" list will be random. Hence, the order of the criteria columns in MEGATABLE are also random. How to I force the order of the data frames in "tables" based on unique(tables[[i]]$ACTIVITY)[1]) ? So for example I would decide that in MEGATABLE I want the PLANTING#Criteria to show up first, then the FERTILIZER#Criteria, then the COUNTING#Criteria, etc.

Note that the names of these critera columns have no pattern whatsoever, so I can't order by name.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Does all the data.frames in  `tables` have the same unique values of ACTIVITY.  Based on the input showed, `PLANTING` is showed in the 2nd list element., but why  you are doing the `unique(tables[[i]]$ACTIVITY)[1])` which seems to have only a single unique value

Comment: If you want a custom order, you could create a vector `v1 <- c("PLANTING", "FERTILIZER"); bind_rows(tables[match(sapply(tables, function(x) x$ACTIVITY[1]), v1)])`

Comment: Hi. Yes tables can potentially have two different activities but since they have the same criteria columns, ordering by one or the other doesn't make a difference practically. Great thank you. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hello again. I just tried this. It doesn't work because I have multiple tables of each "type".  I need to find a way of reordering tables based on the activity and then binding it.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked (there may be a cleaner way. I'd be happy to find out) :

```
v1 <- c("PLANTING","FERTILIZER","DRAINAGE","IRRIGATION")

b <- list()
for (j in 1:length(v1)) {
      a <- list()
for (i in 1:length(tables)) {
    if (unique(tables[[i]]$ACTIVITY)[1] == v1[j]) {
      k <- length(a) + 1
      a[[k]] <- tables[[i]]
      b[[j]] <- bind_rows(a)
    } 
  }
}

MEGATABLE <- bind_rows(b)
```